# How do I get dataset page number using getByUid()

Tags: jquery, listview, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile, kendo-datasource

I have a listview using LoadMore.  The data-click loads a detail view and I am fetching the data from the existing dataset using getByUid().

```
data = dsOfferList.getByUid(e.view.params.uid);
```

Is there a way I can know what page of the datasource that record belongs?  If I use dsOfferList.page(), I get the page number of the dataset after its last change event, not necessarily the page the listview item came from.

For example, say I have a dataset with 200 total records and I am using serverPaging and pageSize of 50. Intially, dsOfferList.page() will return 1. I then scroll down the list and click the Load More button.  Now dsOfferList.page() will return 2.  But if I scroll back up the list a few items, those items (still loaded in the DOM) came from page 1.  I need to be able to click one of the listview items and know if it was loaded from the page 1 datasource or the page 2 datasource.

How can I get the page number of the clicked listview item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I have not found a way to access the current datasource.page() from schema.parse() however, you can from datasource.change().  I ended up using the datasource.change() function to push the returned data row-by-row (including the page variable) into a second datasource object.  So now every time the datasource fires, it automatically updates the second datasource with the data, including the page variable that I needed.

One thing to remember, the UIDs for the second datasource are different even though you are passing the UID from the first datasource.  I set the schema.id in both datasources and utilize this when referencing a particular row of data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
data = dsOfferList.getByUid(e.view.params.uid);
var index = dsOfferList.data().indexOf(data);
var page = Math.round(index/dsOfferList.pageSize()) + 1;
```

Comment: Perfect. That does it!

Comment: Sorry @Petur Subev.  Now that I am testing, this doesn't work exactly as I expected.  Using this, the page var changes to "2" at index 26 while dsOfferList.page() is still at 1.